# Why does my router stop serving sites/endpoints?

Tags: router, wireless-router

When I am browsing Imgur, for example, if I move too quickly between images with the right arrow after about 20 images my router will stop serving that endpoint. Other sites will continue to work for a while, but slowly one by one each site I try to go to will stop working. When I restart the router, everything works again.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to reconfigure my (Earthlink) router to prevent it?

Comment: @FrankThomas would that be at the router or ISP level?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Imgur is using all your Internet bandwidth. If you close the Imgur Window before your connection freezes do the other sites then load?

Comment: They do not. extra letters required to post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok and you say it is a router. Are you able to cable your machine directly to the modem? That would eliminate the router being the issue. Also, this could be caused by security software, content filters or Ad Blockers as well.

Comment: I don't use any real security software on my mac, but I use Adblock Plus for Chrome, as well as the "Disable HTML5 Autoplay" extension. Could these be the cause?

Comment: Also, it's common to ask questionw like this as a comment to the original question, rather than as answers.

Comment: AdBlock Plus shouldn't shut down your entire internet like you are experiencing. Does it work better in Safari?

Comment: I just triggered it in Safari.

Comment: Sounds like a router issue. Do you have access to a different router or perhaps yours has a firmware upgrade available?

Comment: I suppose I could complain to Earthlink...